# Coding an online text editor

Tags: javascript, user-interface, text-editor

I am trying to code a text editor using html and javascript. I found the below fiddle where we can type the text in one text area and the preview can be seen in the area below it on clicking the preview button.

I want to get rid of the preview area and have the text bold in the same text area where the text is typed. How can this be achieved.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
#my_textarea{
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    border:thin solid #000;
    color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width:300px;
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:300px;
}
#preview{
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    border:thin solid #000;
    color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    min-height:150px;
    min-width:300px;
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:300px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function formatText(tag) {
   var myTextArea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
   var myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value;
   var selected_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionStart, myTextArea.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(0, myTextArea.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionEnd, myTextAreaValue.length);
   myTextArea.value = before_txt + '<' + tag + '>' + selected_txt + '</' + tag + '>' + after_txt;
}
function preview() {
    var textbox , view ;
    textbox = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
    view = document.getElementById("preview");
    view.innerHTML = textbox.value
}

function onload(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById("my_textarea");
    textarea.onkeypress = function(e){
        if( e.which === 13)
        {
            this.value += "<br>";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="onload();">
<input type="button" value="bold" onClick="formatText ('b');" /> 
<input type="button" value="italic" onClick="formatText ('i');" /> 
<input type="button" value="underline" onClick="formatText ('u');" /><br><br>
<textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_textarea"></textarea><br><br>
<div id="preview"></div><br>
<button id="btn" onClick="preview();">Preview</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZ6Va/

Comment: You can't, `textarea` can't have HTML. You've to use for example an editable div or pre element instead of a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `contenteditable` HTML attribute:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can <b>be edited</b> by the user.
</div>
```

[More info on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Comment: Thanks. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep the js/view**

If your audience is HTML savvy, you may want to keep the textarea with JavaScript to update a viewer. An editable `<div>` may seem a nice feature, but it allows users to copy/paste from a Word document, and with that comes an *unbelievable* load of MS tagging, much of it empty. And who wants to look at such text in its raw form in a database?!?!

Below is an editor that gives

- a bit more tagging help - buttons with **shortcut keys** - that may be of value,
- dynamic updating of the preview

and while not following the original request to be an editable area without javascript, it spares your database (and you, if you have to look at the raw text)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathTo/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    updCont();//in case existing text
    var ht = window.innerHeight - $("#dvInput").css("height").replace(/[^.0-9]/g, '') - 30;
    if(ht<200) ht = 200;//display height minimum (may extend a bit below page)
    $("#dvCont").css("height", ht + "px");
    $("#txtCont").keydown(function(e){
        var curKey = e.which ? e.which : e.key;
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey){
            if([56,190,80,65,83,76,85,79].indexOf(curKey)>-1)
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
            if(curKey == 56) fmt("bull");// *
            else if(curKey == 190) fmt("indnt");// >
            else if(curKey == 80) fmt("para");// P
            else if(curKey == 65) fmt("href");// A
            else if(curKey == 83) fmt("spn");// S
            else if(curKey == 76) fmt("li");// L
            else if(curKey == 85) fmt("ul");// U
            else if(curKey == 79) fmt("ol");// O
        }else if(e.ctrlKey){
            if([66,73,13,85].indexOf(curKey)>-1)
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
            if(curKey == 66) fmt("bld");// B
            else if(curKey == 73) fmt("ital");// I
            else if(curKey == 85) fmt("uLine");// U
            else if(curKey == 13) fmt("crlf");// [enter]
        }
        updCont();
    });
//    $("#inp").keydown(function(e){alert(e.which)})
});
function updCont(){
    $("#dvCont").html($("#txtCont").val());//stuff the display div with textarea html text
}
function fmt(inAct){
    //common needs
    var oTxt = $("#txtCont");
    var s = oTxt[0].selectionStart;
    var e = oTxt[0].selectionEnd;
    var raVal = [oTxt.val().substring(0, s), oTxt.val().substring(s, e), oTxt.val().substring(e), s, e];
    var ofstStart = 0;
    var ofstEnd = 0;
    if(inAct=="bld"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<b>" + raVal[1]  + "</b>" + raVal[2]);
        //if you don't want text selected, add raVal[1].length to ofstStart 
        ofstStart = 3;
        //uncomment to place cursor after closing tag (also unselect - set ofstStart to same point)
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="ital"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<i>" + raVal[1]  + "</i>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 3;
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="uLine"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<u>" + raVal[1]  + "</u>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 3;
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="ul"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<ul>" + raVal[1]  + "</ul>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 4;
        //ofstEnd = 5;
    }else if(inAct=="ol"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<ol>" + raVal[1]  + "</ol>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 4;
        //ofstEnd = 5;
    }else if(inAct=="li"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<li style=''>" + raVal[1]  + "</li>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 13;
        //ofstEnd = 5;
    }else if(inAct=="indnt"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<div class='dnt'>" + raVal[1]  + "</div>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 17;
        //ofstEnd = 5;
    }else if(inAct=="bull"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<br />&nbsp; &bull; " + raVal[1]  + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 20;
    }else if(inAct=="para"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<p>" + raVal[1]  + "</p>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 3;
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="href"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<a href='' class='' title=''>" + raVal[1]  + "</a>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 29;
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="spn"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<span class='' style=''>" + raVal[1]  + "</span>" + raVal[2]);
        ofstStart = 24;
        //ofstEnd = 4;
    }else if(inAct=="crlf"){
        oTxt.val(raVal[0] + "<br />" + raVal[1]  + raVal[2]);
        ofstEnd = 5;
    }
    updCont();
    //put cursor at end of selected range (ignores start if no selected text)
    oTxt[0].selectionStart = s + ofstStart;
    oTxt[0].selectionEnd = s + ofstStart + raVal[1].length;
    oTxt[0].focus();
}
</script>
<style>
.dnt{margin-left:40px;}
.styleBtn{width:20px;margin:2px 10px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#EEE;float:left;text-align:center;}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="dvInput">
<div style="border:1px solid black;border-radius:5px;background-color:silver;font-weight:bold;padding:2px 5px;float:left;">
    <div style="float:left;margin:2px 20px;">Text Input:</div>
    <span onclick="fmt('bld');" title="CTRL+B: Bold selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn"><b>B</b></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('ital');" title="CTRL+I: Italicize selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn"><i>I</i></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('uLine');" title="CTRL+U: Underline selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn"><u>U</u></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('ul');" title="CTRL+Shift+U: List Group <ul> (unordered) around highlighted/selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn" style="height:19px;font-size:5.5pt;">
            •__<br>
            •__
        </div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('ol');" title="CTRL+Shift+O: Ord List Group <ol> (ordered) around highlighted/selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn" style="height:19px;font-size:5.5pt;padding-top:2px;">
            1__<br>
            2__
        </div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('li');" title="CTRL+Shift+L: List Item <li> around highlighted/selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn" style="width:30px;">&lt;&bull;></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('indnt');" title="CTRL+Shift+>: <div> Indent a selected block of text\n(No remove shortcut.\nManually delete <div></div> to undo/outdent)">
        <div class="styleBtn">></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('bull');" title="CTRL+Shift+*: Bullet (and new line)">
        <div class="styleBtn">&bull;</div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('para');" title="CTRL+Shift+P: Paragraph <p> around highlighted/selected text">
        <div class="styleBtn">&para;</div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('crlf');" title="CTRL+Enter: New Line <br>">
        <div class="styleBtn">&ldsh;</div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('href');" title="CTRL+Shift+A: <a href>">
        <div class="styleBtn" style="width:33px;">&lt;a></div>
    </span>
    <span onclick="fmt('spn');" title="CTRL+Shift+S: <span>">
        <div class="styleBtn" style="width:48px;">&lt;spn></div>
    </span>
<!-- <input id="inp" size="2">-enter char, get ascii number -->
</div>
<textarea id="txtCont" rows="10" style="width:100%;" name="myText"
>lorem ipsum dolor magnificum est labat et nobis pacem</textarea><br />
</div>

Display:
<div id="dvCont" style="border:1px solid black;border-radius:5px;overflow-y:auto;"></div>
```